# Why useEffect is triggered when I use a function from props (function is not changing)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The Main component is calling a Modal/Dialog.

```
[...]
  const closeDialog = () => setIsOpenDialog(false);
  return (
      <MyDialog
        isOpen={isOpenDialog}
        onClose={closeDialog}
      />
  );
```

The MyDialog code is:

```
[...]
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('This removes dialog states (data)!')
  }, [onClose]);

export default function MyDialog({
  isOpen,
  onClose,
}) {
    return (
    <Dialog
      isOpen={isOpen}
      onClose={onClose}
      dialogTitle="Add/Edit"
      onClickCancel={onClose}
    >
    [...]
    </Dialog>
);
}
```

When I click on Cancel and call `onClose`, I can see that the `useEffect` is **triggered**. I would like to ask what is the reason? My understanding is that it shouldn't since the `onClose` function object (from `props`) does not change.

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` hook in React runs when any of the dependencies in its dependency array change. In your case, the `useEffect` has a dependency on the `onClose` prop. Therefore, it would run every time the `onClose` prop changes.

However, even though the `onClose` function doesn't change in your code, `useEffect` might still run due to the way JavaScript handles function identities. In JavaScript, every time you define a function, it's a new instance, even if it does exactly the same thing.

So, in your case, you're defining `closeDialog` as a new function in your render function every time your component re-renders. That means, from React's perspective, `onClose` is a new function every time, which triggers the `useEffect`.

To solve this, you can use the `useCallback` hook to ensure your `closeDialog` function has a stable identity across renders unless its dependencies change:

```
const closeDialog = React.useCallback(() => setIsOpenDialog(false), []);
```

In the example above, `useCallback` returns a memoized version of the function that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. In this case, the dependencies array is empty ([]), meaning the identity of the `closeDialog` function will be stable across re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

The **`useEffect`** hook in the **`MyDialog`** component is **triggered** because the dependency array **`onClose`** is specified. This means that the effect will run whenever the value of **`onClose`** changes. Though the function reference for **`onClose`** remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the **`MyDialog`** component, the effect is not comparing the function reference itself, it's comparing the value of **`onClose`** in each render cycle.  When **`onClose`** function is invoked, **`MyDialog`** component is rendered again, and then a new instance of **`onClose`** function is created. This causes the value of **`onClose`** to change which triggers the **`useEffect`** hook.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, this term is known as referential equality.

**Example:**

*First render*

```
// This has an address in memory: 111
const function1 = () =>{
// ...
}
```

So when react re-renders the component it re-declares this function

*Second render*

```
// This has an address in memory: 112
const function1 = () =>{
// ...
}
```

So if a useEffect has function1 as a dependency it will compare the declaration in the *Second Sender* with the declaration in the *First Render*.

So it will result in `111 !== 112`
Then depending on this condition it will re-run the useEffect.

To solve this issue:

**For functions:** you can use the `useCallback` hook

```
const function1 = useCallback(()=>{
// ...
},[])
```

**For objects and arrays** you can use`useMemo` hook

```
const object1 = useMemo(()=>({name: 'test user'}),[])
const array1 = useMemo(()=>([1, 2, 3, 4]),[])
```